# Can I determine my exit IP on Tor using the control protocol

Tags: protocols, tor

Is there a way to find my ip the world sees when connecting
over TOR.

Presently I send a http request to whatsmyip.org, I could not
find a way using the control protocol. Is there a way ?

Answer (score 2):

No problem, please see the following example...

https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/examples/exit_used.html

Answer (score 0):

Just open google search and write inside it "my ip" or "my ip address"
Cause i think tor doesnt have this option

Comment: I'm using Tor in my application, I need to do it programmatically via the control port..